How do I print the data collected from Beautifulsoup to a label on a TKinter GuI
I am working on an app that gets product price info from a website using Beautiful Soup.
Once I have the data i want to display all the data on a label using TKinter. I have all the data that comes from the website go into a list but for some reason when I try printing to the label using the print_data method it only prints one line. see my code below.
Can someone please help?
    def fetch_price_data(self):
        self.URL = ""
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        num = 1
        for i in self.PRODUCT_URL_LIST:
            self.URL = i
            response = self.requests.get(self.URL)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
            data = (str(num) + " " + soup.find_all("h1")[0].text + " " +
                    soup.find_all(class_="product-price")[0].text.split("€")[1])
            self.listed_products.append(data)
            num += 1
            print(data)

    def print_data(self):
        for i in range(len(Fetchdata.listed_products)):
            return Fetchdata.listed_products[i] + "\n"

    def make_gui(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.app_menu()
        self.window.config(width=1100, height=560, background="#68BB59")
        self.window.minsize(width=1100, height=560)
        self.window.title("ALEO & MORE DATA MANAGER")
        self.window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        # canvas = Canvas()
        # canvas.config(width=1075, height=480)
        # canvas.place(x=10, y=10)
        get_data_btn = Button(master=self.window, text="SYNC", width=15, height=2, font=("arial", 10)
                              , background="#D4D4D4")
        get_data_btn.place(x=960, y=505)
        checkInternetHttplib()
        # canvas.create_text(200, 60, text="Hello Everyone", font=("Arial", 10, "bold"))
        lable = Label(width=153, height=32, text=self.print_data() + "\n")
        lable.place(x=10, y=10)

I have tried to use a canvas to print the info on but that too did not work.
I am new to python so sorry if my code is all over the place.

don't use return in for-loop because it exist loop at once - and it can't run code for next elements on list. But you have to convert all string from list to one string - like "\n".join(Fetchdata.listed_products)

put all import at the beginning of file - it helps to see what modules are needed to run code. So move from bs4 import BeautifulSoup to the beginning of your script. See more PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code

you can set self.URL in one line for self.URL in self.PRODUCT_URL_LIST:

if you want to find item [0] then you can use find instead of find_all - soup.find("h1").text and soup.find(class_="product-price").text.split("€")[1]

data = f'{num} {soup.find("h1").text} {soup.find(class_="product-price").text.split("€")[1]}'

you can use enumerate to set num in one line for num, self.URL in enumerate(self.PRODUCT_URL_LIST, 1): without num = 1 and without num += 1

Plain and simple
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

class WebScraperApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listed_products = []
        self.PRODUCT_URL_LIST = [
            "https://example.com/product1",
            "https://example.com/product2",
            "https://example.com/product3"
        ]
        self.window = None
        self.label = None
    
    def fetch_price_data(self):
        self.listed_products = []
        for i, url in enumerate(self.PRODUCT_URL_LIST, start=1):
            response = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
            product_name_elem = soup.find_all("h1")
            product_price_elem = soup.find(class_="product-price")
            
            if product_name_elem and product_price_elem:
                product_name = product_name_elem[0].text.strip()
                product_price = product_price_elem.text.strip().split("€")[1]
                data = f"{i}. {product_name} - {product_price}"
                self.listed_products.append(data)
            else:
                self.listed_products.append(f"Product information not found for URL: {url}")
        
        # Update label text with fetched data
        self.update_label_text()
                
    def make_gui(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.config(width=600, height=400, background="#68BB59")
        self.window.title("Web Scraper App")
        self.window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        
        sync_button = Button(self.window, text="SYNC", command=self.fetch_price_data)
        sync_button.place(x=500, y=350)
        
        self.label = Label(self.window, width=60, height=20, text="", justify="left", anchor="nw")
        self.label.place(x=20, y=20)
        
        self.window.mainloop()
    
    def update_label_text(self):
        data = "\n".join(self.listed_products)
        self.label.config(text=data)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = WebScraperApp()
    app.make_gui()


Thank you for your input Victor. Grateful to you for taking the time to help. I have never used the enumerate function before so will look this up and hopefully use it more often. :)

Don't use return in for-loop because it exits loop at once
and it can't run code for next elements on list.
You have to convert all elements from list to one string and return this string.
def print_data(self):
    # - before loop -
    result = ""

    # - loop -
    for item in Fetchdata.listed_products:
        result += item + "\n"

    # - after loop -
    return result 

But you don't need for-loop for this.
def print_data(self):
    return "\n".join(Fetchdata.listed_products)

And it will create text without '\n' after last line - so you don't get empty line at the bottom in Label
You could even do it directly in Label
label = Label(..., text="\n".join(Fetchdata.listed_products))


Thank you for your help Furas. I sure will take this on board. Everyday is a learning day :). as soon as I removed the return statement in the loop it started list all found data in the gui label. Now its about formatting. I am new at this so taking it one day at a time.
